# How to save DateTime to MongoDB with Timezone intact?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, apollo

Hi Im trying to save time and date to Mongo DB but it seems to be changing the date to another format and even when I try in that format it removes the timezone and changes the time

2022-03-30T09:00:46-07:00

becomes

2022-03-30T16:00:46.000+00:00

*My issue is when I send emails to tell clients the time it sends the wrong time completely causing confusion.
How can I ensure the timezone get saved in Mongo.

Im using graphql as an api lang if needed.

Comment: `2022-03-30T16:00:46.000+00:00` is time based on UTC0 (sometimes instead of `+00:00` You can see `Z`) which is correct portable format. Mongodb converts time based on server's timezone, so seems like You're in UTC-7 and mongodb changes date to universal format which can be converted automatically on clientside.

Comment: Date/times in MongoDB are stored as UTC time - always and only. It is the responsibility of your client application to display the time as local time according to end user client application settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was no way to do it. It's best to store timezone separate and convert

Answer (score 0):

sender:

new Date().toISOString()

[image: 1]

Receiver:

idea: parse iso string to iso date

package: date-fns

method: parseISO(inputISOString)